# Safari keeps downloading data when Gmail is open

Tags: safari, gmail

If I have a visible tab (non occluded window) open on Gmail, my Safari (8.0 running on Yosemite) keeps downloading data at a rate of 1 MB/s. The same does not happen with Chrome.

I'd like to understand what this is for, and if possible, make it stop.

Some info:

- logs don't show anything suspicious.
- caches are ok
- network panel of web inspector shows no activity
- lsof output: https://gist.github.com/Agos/78fa61943af31d634a99

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening, but the MailPlane folks have apparently been dealing with it already. They have a beta that is supposed to fix it.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, but my data rate is 3 MB/s down and 300 KB/s up.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Chat in Gmail looks like it sovled the issue for me.